# C# Linq - Given two lists, how do I tell if either of them are contained in each other

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
ListA:

"Brown"
"Green"
"Yellow"
"Orange"

ListB:

"Yellow"
"Orange"
```

I want to return true if ListA or ListB is contained in each other. In this case ListB is a part of ListA. It's not necessarily true that ListB will be smaller.

The only solution I can think of is doing Union's on both sides, i.e. first ListA with ListB, then ListB with ListA, and return true if and only if both are true.

Is this the best approach, any other way?

I'm hoping for a Linq solution

Comment: Do you mean are the elements in the list unique? Yes, they are unique strings.

Comment: I'm not good enough with Linq to give a proper answer but roughly if the intersection of the two lists is the same size as the smaller list then the smaller list is contained in the larger. The reason I'm not confident about doing it with Linq is because I'm always fuzzy on whether using Intersect will give duplicates if they are in your list or just unique items. If you don't have duplicates in either list though then you don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
int count = ListA.Intersect(ListB).Count();
if ((count == ListA.Count()) || (count == ListB.Count())) {
    // One list contains other
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works as expected if the lists don't contain duplicate elements, and the OP has confirmed that this is the case here. But if your lists did potentially contain dupes then you can't rely on this technique.

Comment: Yup, if I could mark both answers, I would mark the other one as well, cause I'm sure there would be others who would value that one more.

Answer (score 4):

Check whether `a.Except(b)` or `b.Except(a)` is empty.

Comment: And to check it use the `Any()` extension method, not the `Count()` :-) (I'm on my personal crusade to teach other persons to use `Any()` because it's O(1) instead of `Count()` that is O(n))

Comment: Is comparing empty merely checking 0 size or is there a more appropriate way of doing it .. let me search for it.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how the performance of this compares to using the intersect trick? I'm guessing this would be quicker because using the Any it would basically return the moment it found any member of a that wasn't in b (or vice versa)...

Comment: @xanatos: Yes; I fully agree.  (but I forgot to mention it)  You can also call `.Skip(x).Any()` instead of `.Count() > x`

Comment: @Chris: However, this involves more loops.  I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [intersect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) and check if the resulting set is the same as either set.

Comment: Not "the same". There could be repeated elements. And the order of the new set could not be the same as one of the original ones.

Comment: Of course. Not the same as in objects. Since we are dealing with sets, you would just use the count.

Comment: Hmm.. If this works, then I'd rather do this. Xanatos, the elements are unique strings.